# How to keep reading user input with pauses for custom Alexa skill

Tags: alexa-voice-service

I want to make a Alexa custom skill that reads sentence from user. I am currently trying to do that with the `query` type slot but the problem is that Alexa does not allow any pause on the input. User needs to speak the sentence really fast without keeping any pauses or Alexa will interrupt.

I would need to give the user more time to form the sentence when the skill is activated. Is this even possible? Alternatively can I start some active input reading that would send read input to the lambda constantly and I could break it when a certain word is received?

Answer (score 0):

Please note that this is currently not a supported feature of the Alexa Skills Kit. It is not possible to control the way Alexa listens to users, not even simulate a user interaction by code to avoid ending the session.